# $\int_{a}^{b}\left(\frac{\cos(x)\tan^{\pi}(x)}{\sin^3(x)}\right)dx$

Tags: integration

I've got an integration problem; I don't know how to go from the left 'red' side to the right. Can someone help me?

Assuming $a<b$ and $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$:

---

$$\int_{a}^{b}\left(\frac{\cos(x)\tan^{\pi}(x)}{\sin^3(x)}\right)dx=\int_{a}^{b}\left(\frac{1}{\sin^3(x)}\cdot \left(\cos(x)\tan^{\pi}(x)\right)\right)dx=$$
$$\int_{a}^{b}\left(\csc^3(x)\cdot \left(\cos(x)\tan^{\pi}(x)\right)\right)dx=\int_{a}^{b}\left(\csc^3(x)\cos(x)\tan^{\pi}(x)\right)dx=$$
$$\int_{a}^{b}\left(\csc^2(x)\cot(x)\tan^{\pi}(x)\right)dx=\int_{a}^{b}\left(\tan^{\pi-1}\left(x\right)\csc^2(x)\right)dx$$

---

$$\color{red}{\int_{a}^{b}\left(\tan^{\pi-1}\left(x\right)\csc^2(x)\right)dx=\left[\frac{\tan^{\pi-2}(x)}{\pi-2}\right]_{a}^{b}}=$$

$$\left(\frac{\tan^{\pi-2}(b)}{\pi-2}\right)-\left(\frac{\tan^{\pi-2}(a)}{\pi-2}\right)=\frac{\tan^{\pi-2}(b)-\tan^{\pi-2}(a)}{\pi-2}$$

Comment: $\int { \tan ^{ \pi -1 }{ (x) }  } \csc ^{ 2 }{ (x) } dx\quad \neq \quad \frac { \tan ^{ \pi -2 }{ (x) }  }{ \pi -2 } $

Comment: Oh sure it is!!!

Comment: Oh sorry didnt see that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace $\tan$ with $\cot$:

\begin{align}
\int_a^b \tan^u x \csc^2 x\,dx &= \int_a^b \cot^{-u} x \csc^2 x\,dx\\
&= -\int_a^b \cot^{-u} x \cot' x \,dx\\
&= -\biggl[\frac{\cot^{1-u} x}{1-u}\biggr]_a^b\\
&= \biggl[ \frac{\tan^{u-1} x}{u-1}\biggr]_a^b.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

$$
\frac{\tan^{\beta-1}(x)}{\sin^2(x)} = \frac{\tan^2(x)}{\sin^2(x)}\tan^{\beta-3}(x)
$$
this leads to
$$
\int_a^b\frac{\tan^2(x)}{\sin^2(x)}\tan^{\beta-3}(x)dx = \int_a^b\sec^2 x\tan^{\beta-3}(x)dx 
$$
we have
$$
\dfrac{d}{dx}\tan^\alpha x = \sec^2 x\tan^{\alpha-1}x
$$